# Receive app-to-app response, but app that will be called has no intent of its own

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio, intentservice

Thanks in advance for the help, i need to make a module for react-native that gets a deeplink open an application and gets the return of a 'data' that the application returned, but I'm new to react-native, this involves java (with android) looking at the module code react-native-activity-result.
My test sample code to try to perform the module

Codigo do módulo react-native-activity-result

```java
  @ReactMethod
  public void startActivityForResult(int requestCode, String action, ReadableMap data, Promise promise) {
      Activity activity = getReactApplicationContext().getCurrentActivity();
      Intent intent = new Intent(action);
      intent.putExtras(Arguments.toBundle(data));
      activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
      mPromises.put(requestCode, promise);
}
```

application code that needs to be opened by deeplink

```java
Private final int REQUEST_CODE = 1001;
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putString("amount","0000000000100");
  bundle.putString("currencyPosition","CURRENCY_AFTER_AMOUNT");
  bundle.putString("currencyCode","986");
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("getnet://pagamento/v1/payment"));
  intent.putExtras(bundle);
  startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

My test sample code to try to perform the module

```java
  @ReactMethod
  public void startActivityForResultUnintentionally(int requestCode, String deepLink, ReadableMap data, Promise promise) {
      Activity activity = getReactApplicationContext().getCurrentActivity();
      Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(deepLink));
      intent.putExtras(Arguments.toBundle(data));
      activity.startActivityForResultUnintentionally(intent, requestCode);
      mPromises.put(requestCode, promise);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got 1 I took the action parameter and in place I added a deepLink parameter, then where the action parameter made sense I put the ACTION.VIEW, and another parameter added the Deeplink converting from String to Uri.

```java
@ReactMethod
    public void startActivityForResult(int requestCode, String deeplink, ReadableMap data, Promise promise) {
        Activity activity = getReactApplicationContext().getCurrentActivity();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(deeplink));
        intent.putExtras(Arguments.toBundle(data));
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
        mPromises.put(requestCode, promise);
    }
```